# In Powershell, how do you replace string based on record identifier in a flat file

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I have a comma-separated, flat file with extension .psa, such as abc12.psa, category123.psa etc. in my C:\psa\Prevalidation folder. There are different record types in the file. The record descriptor (first field) is called 'product','fixture','position' etc.

What I want to do is for every record starting with the word 'fixture', if the 78th field is a blank, then populate this field with the string called 'Universal'.

I have been trying for doing the same when it is position-agnostic, but dont know (1) how do I  pass the position parameter asking the script to check only if the 78th field is a null or not (2) when the first field is 'fixture' (3) Since I am converting the files to a temp.csv I want to rename them back to their originam names, but am not sure how to do that.

```
foreach($file in (dir C:\psa\Prevalidation\*.psa)){
Copy-Item $file.fullname C:\psa\Prevalidation\temp1.csv
Get-Content C:\psa\Prevalidation\temp1.csv | ForEach-Object { $_.replace("","Universal") }
```

Any help on this is deeply appreciated.
Thanks,
Sanders.

Comment: Can you give a example of wat you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to turn something like this:

```
Descriptor,Field2,Field3,Field4
product,Data2,,Data4
fixture,Data2,,Data4
```

Into this:

```
"Descriptor","Field2","Field3","Field4"
"product","Data2","","Data4"
"fixture","Data2","Universal","Data4"
```

Here is some code that will do this.

```
$csv = Import-Csv abc12.psa -Delimiter ','
# 77 is 78th field (starting from 0)
$fieldName = ($csv[0] | gm | ? {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"})[77].Name
$csv | % {
    if ($_.Descriptor -eq 'fixture' -and -not $_.$fieldName ) {
        $_.$fieldName = "Universal"
    }
}

$csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File C:\output.csv
```

Here is a version that is field index agnostic:

```
$csv = Import-Csv abc12.psa -Delimiter ','
$fieldNames = ($csv[0] | gm | ? {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"}) | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$csv | % {
    if ($_.Descriptor -eq 'fixture') {
        foreach ($fieldName in $fieldNames) {
            if (-not $_.$fieldName) {
                $_.$fieldName = "Universal"
            }
        }
    }
}

$csv | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Out-File C:\output.csv
```

Comment: Thanks Andy for the code. But how do I do it for every psa file in C:\psa\Prevalidation folder and also I wanted to change the csv file back to its original file name after I do the replace.

Comment: Also, I am getting the following error message while running the script.... Unable to index into an object of type Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition.
At C:\cap_sps\powershell\fixturereplace.ps1:3 char:68
+ $fieldName = ($csv[0] | gm | ? {$_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty"})[ <<<< 77].Name
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (77:Int32) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotIndex

Comment: @user982201 You already have a loop that is doing what you asking. You should run this code for each of your temp1.csv files. Since I don't have an example of you file I could only test with my example CSV. To help you further please upload and link to an example of one of your CSV files.

Comment: Wheres the upload link here where I can put up my file as an example? Also, I cannot paste my file contents here since only 600 characters are allowed to used as your comment..

Comment: @user982201 Use something like paste bin or dropbox and link to it.